# Is there a shorthand syntax for constructors with some optional arguments in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I want to use the "pseudo-keyword" syntax for constructing a class:

`new Foo({ bar, baz, quux })`

However, there are also a couple of arguments that are required:
`new Foo(x, y, { bar, baz, quux })`.

Is there a way to get this sort of functionality without repetition?

```js
class Foo {
  public x: number;
  public y: number;
  public bar: string;
  public baz: string;
  public quux: string;

  constructor(
    x: number,
    y: number,
    {
        bar = "a",
        baz = "b",
        quux = "c",
    }: {
        bar?: string;
        baz?: string;
        quux?: string;
    } = {}
  ) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    this.bar = bar;
    this.baz = baz;
    this.quux = quux;
  }
}
```

What idiom am I overlooking?

Comment: if you mean optional parameters, you should put them last in the constructior parameters and use the questionmark to make them optional. constructor({}: {}, x?: number, y? :number)

Comment: To be clear, `x` and `y` represent the only _required_ parameters. The "keyword arguments" in the anonymous object type represent the optional parameters with default values. I want to be able to construct the object with only a couple of needed overrides, e.g. `new Foo(1, 2, { quux: "meh"})`.